# Using pip install within PyScripter

Tags: python, pip, pyscripter

I want to install a Python package within a script in PyScripter.

```
import pip
package = 'xlsxwriter'
pip.main(['install', package])
```

Following error occurs:

```
Collecting xlsxwriter
  Downloading XlsxWriter-0.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136kB)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 587, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 871, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 577, in _download_url
    progress_indicator = DownloadProgressBar(max=total_length).iter
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 158, in __init__
    super(WindowsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 82, in __init__
    super(InterruptibleMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\ui.py", line 118, in __init__
    super(DownloadProgressMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\progress\helpers.py", line 58, in __init__
    if self.file.isatty() and self.hide_cursor:
  File "<string>", line 523, in __getattr__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 150, in __getattr__
    return syncreq(self, consts.HANDLE_GETATTR, name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
    return conn.sync_request(handler, oid, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 434, in sync_request
    raise obj
AttributeError: DebugOutput instance has no attribute 'isatty'
```

Why does this error occur und how to fix it? The same code works well when using the Python interpreter directly, but not with PyScripter for some reason.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: is it installing fine directly using pip? I mean by `pip install xlsxwriter`

Comment: Yes, installing the package works fine using {pip install} via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import subprocess

# implement pip as a subprocess:
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 
'<packagename>'])
```